# Beamer -- not indenting itemize in a single environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

The output in the MWE posted at the end of this post is shown below. Notice how the default indentation from itemize gives an asymmetric slide w.r.t the spacing to the left and right of the itemize environment. How can I push the bullet points to the left so that the spaces to the left and right are the same? Such a solution would ideally be:

- implementable on a one-off basis, so that it is applied when necessary (since some itemize environments should be given the default indentation)
- independent of the margin size, so that the solution doesn't need to be changed when the margin size is changed

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
\item tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
\item ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{itemize}
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
\item cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5cm}` or something along those lines.

Comment: That's a global solution though, see my first requirement. I don't want every single usage of itemize to conform to those specifications, I only want to change the margins on *particular uses* of the environment

Answer (score 3):

The left margin of an itemization can be adjusted via `\leftmargini`. To do this only for a specific itemization, adjust it inside a group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A title}

normal text

{
  \setlength\leftmargini{0pt}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  \item tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  \item ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  \item cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
  \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
}  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is really close to what I want -- but is it possible to have the left edge of the triangles line up with the "n" in "normal text"?  Obviously I can guess-and-test what number to put into \leftmargini{_pt}, but is there a more principled way?