# Beamer presentation with itemize exceed text capacity

Tags: beamer, enumerate, enumitem, compilation-error, capacity

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Tactics used for career advancement}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Consistently exceed performance expectations
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \end{frame}

Removing the `enumitem` package fixes the problem, but in the real life I need that package to remove the left margin. In the real document I use:
`\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]`

Comment: don't use the `enumitem` package with beamer, they are incompatible.

Comment: @samcarter I need it to remove the left margin `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]`

Comment: you can set the `leftmargini` instead.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435822/36296 for an example

Comment: or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422886/beamer-not-indenting-itemize-in-a-single-environment/422937#422937 for no margin at all.